# How to add more elements in ReactJS state array?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

`this.state.counter.map` is not a function I need to add object and map to counter
and I need to create and push to counter array and map to counter and show in this browser how to do that?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './counter';

class Counters extends Component {
  state = { 
    counter: [
      {value:0, id:1},
      {value:0, id:2},
      {value:0, id:3},
      {value:0, id:4},
    ]
  };

  // function for create new array and map to him for delete one of counter in browser
  DeleteButten = counterId => {
    const counter = this.state.counter.filter(c =>c.id !== counterId);
    this.setState({counter});
  };

  // this function for push new object to array and show in browser
  AddCounter = () => {
    const counter = this.state.counter.push({value:0 ,id:5});
    console.log(this.state.counter);
    this.setState({counter}); // error this.state.counter.map is not a function i need help to add object and map to counter
  };

  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counter.map(counter => (
          <Counter
            key={counter.id}
            onDelete{this.DeleteButten}
            value={counter.value}
            id={counter.id} selected={true}
          />
        )}
        <button onClick={this.AddCounter} className='btn btn-outline-info btn-sm m-2'> ADD result</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counters;
```

Comment: Usually this means the variable where you call `.map()` is not an array, probably this is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code this line:

```js
const counter = this.state.counter.push({value:0 ,id:5});
```

You're mutating the state array directly, which is not allowed in React.

You can either (shallow) clone the array and modify it:

```js
// This does a shallow clone of the array.
const newCounter = [...this.state.counter];

// Modify the new array.
newCounter.push({ value: 0, id: 5 });

// Set the new array back to the state using setState.
this.setState({ counter: newCounter });
```

Or, you can use the shorter syntax for just appending new elements and making a new array at the same time:

```js
// Append a new element to the new cloned array.
this.setState({ counter: [...this.state.counter, { value: 0, id: 5 });

// Or you can put the element at the front if you like :)
this.setState({ counter: [{ value: 0, id: 5 }, ...this.state.counter]);
```

The triple dot (`[...array]`) syntax is called **spread**, and can be used with both arrays and objects to conveniently clone or reconstruct new array or objects! [Check out the MDN docs about it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

---

One more little thing to improve is the above code works mostly, but note that React `setState` is async, there's a chance for race condition
Say for example you call your `AddCounter` method multiple times within the same event loop, the later results may override the previous ones.

Therefore, if you are setting something that depends on the current state, it's recommended to use the callback syntax:

```js
this.setState(state => { counter: [...state.counter, { value: 0, id: 5 }] });
```

[See more details and examples of the async nature of setState in React docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add element to array here is the code :

```
this.setState({counter:...this.state.counter,new_count})
```

`new_count` is what you are trying to push